# Deploy a KJAR to KIE execution server programmatically via REST API

Tags: drools, kie

I want to know if it is possible to deploy a KJAR to the execution server programmatically (via API)?
I can build a KJAR using the following:

```
        final KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
        final KieFileSystem kieFileSystem = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();

        kieFileSystem.write("src/main/resources/" + ClassUtils.convertClassNameToResourcePath(getPackageNameForRule(rule.getValue())) + "/" + rule
                                                        .getCode() + ".drl", rule.getValue());


        return kieServices.newKieBuilder(kieFileSystem).buildAll().getKieModule().getReleaseId();
```

and I can also create a container in the KIE execution server through the REST `KieServicesClient` like this:

```
        KieContainerResource kieContainerResource =
                        new KieContainerResource(containerId, new org.kie.server.api.model.ReleaseId(buildNewReleaseId()));
        kieServicesClient.createContainer(containerId, kieContainerResource);
```

but when I do so I get an exception in the KIE server saying that:

```
kie-server          | 10:54:04,192 ERROR [org.kie.server.services.impl.KieServerImpl] (default task-2) Error creating container 'targeting' for module 'org.default:artifact:1.0.0': java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find KieModule: org.default:artifact:1.0.0
kie-server          |   at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:186)
kie-server          |   at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:176)
kie-server          |   at org.kie.server.services.impl.KieServerImpl.createContainer(KieServerImpl.java:275)
kie-server          |   at org.kie.server.remote.rest.common.resource.KieServerRestImpl.createContainer(KieServerRestImpl.java:157)
kie-server          |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
kie-server          |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
kie-server          |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
kie-server          |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
kie-server          |   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:140)
kie-server          |   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:509)
```

My KIE server is running in a docker container. Do I have to programmatically invoke Maven to deploy my KJAR in the repository inside the docker container? I hope there's an API to do this programmatically. Also how does the Drools Workbench do it?

Answer (score 1):

I found it. There's an API in `org.kie.soup:kie-soup-maven-integration` which one can use like this:

```
        MavenRepository repository = getMavenRepository();

        if (remote) {
            RemoteRepository remoteRepository = new RemoteRepository.Builder("id", "type", "url").build();
            repository.deployArtifact(remoteRepository, releaseId, kjar, pom);
        } else {
            repository.installArtifact(releaseId, kjar, pom);
        }
```